# Integration of confluent hypergeometric function of two variables

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

Is it possible to integrate confluent hypergeometric function of two variables?
I am trying to solve the integral

$\int_0^tx^{n-1}e^{px}\Phi_3(a,b,cx,mx)~dx$

where $n$ is a positive integer, $a,b,c$ and $m$ are positive constants.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^tx^{n-1}e^{px}\Phi_3(a,b,cx,mx)~dx$

$=\int_0^tx^{n-1}e^{px}\sum\limits_{r=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{s=0}^\infty\dfrac{(a)_r(cx)^r(mx)^s}{(b)_{r+s}r!s!}dx$ (accrodindg to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbert_series)

$=\int_0^t\sum\limits_{r=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{s=0}^\infty\dfrac{(a)_rc^rm^sx^{n+r+s-1}e^{px}}{(b)_{r+s}r!s!}dx$

$=\left[\sum\limits_{r=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{s=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{u=0}^{n+r+s-1}\dfrac{(-1)^{n+r+s-u-1}(n+r+s-1)!(a)_rc^rm^sx^ue^{px}}{(b)_{r+s}p^{n+r+s-u}r!s!u!}\right]_0^t$ (according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions)

$=\sum\limits_{r=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{s=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{u=0}^{n+r+s-1}\dfrac{(-1)^{n+r+s-u-1}(n+r+s-1)!(a)_rc^rm^st^ue^{pt}}{(b)_{r+s}p^{n+r+s-u}r!s!u!}-\sum\limits_{r=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{s=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n+r+s-1}(n+r+s-1)!(a)_rc^rm^s}{(b)_{r+s}p^{n+r+s}r!s!}$

Comment: I do have an alternate form  using the alternate Incomplete gamma function; that allows instant validation.  If you are still interested I will post it.  I think it will over run the comment size here.  Although the result won't.  Basically using \Gamma(a,z)  the derivative goes straight to z^(a-1)*e^z  which is the coefficient form you came in with.  Then the parameters can be checked in a flash.

Answer (score 0):

BTW: somebody should check this carefully and erase ths comment; I don't know what I would do with my life if I didn't spend 3/4 of the time correcting mistakes

There are alternate ways to express the answer. For any $f(x)$ having
a taylor expansion around zero we have:

${\displaystyle \intop_{0}^{t}e^{-px}f(}x)dx={\displaystyle \intop_{0}^{t}e^{-px}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}dx={\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\gamma\left(n+1,p\cdot t\right)/p^{n+1}}}$

or the simpler:

$${\displaystyle \intop_{0}^{t}e^{-x}f(}p\cdot x)dx={\displaystyle \intop_{0}^{t}e^{-x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}p^{n}\cdot x^{n}dx={\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\gamma\left(n+1,t\right)\cdot p^{n}}}$$

Whenever the summation/intgration can be switched.

While the last just switches a function for the infinite series variable;
an alternate expansion in $t$ yields a sequence of ascending order
polynomials $p_{n}$; $n$ is the order.

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\cdot p_{n}(p)\cdot t^{n}$

This is obvious when the answer is thrown in a coefficient matrix
form (double Taylor expansion) and the properties of $\gamma\left(n,t\right)$
are examined.  In addition the coefficients of the polynomials are simple to write down.

A third representation has been redacted for editing due to errors.
rrogers

Comment: Thanks for trying to match my result to some known special functions. Your $\Phi_2$ function has $9$ parameters, while the real $\Phi_2$ function in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbert_series has only $5$ parameters. What is the meaning of your $\Phi_2$ function?

Comment: I think you match the second term to some known special functions wrongly. In fact $\sum\limits_{r=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{s=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n+r+s-1}(n+r+s-1)!(a)_rc^rm^s}{(b)_{r+s}p^{n+r+s}r!s!}=\sum\limits_{r=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{s=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n+r+s-1}\Gamma(n+r+s)(a)_rc^rm^s}{(b)_{r+s}p^{n+r+s}r!s!}=\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}\Gamma(n)}{p^n}\sum\limits_{r=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{s=0}^\infty\dfrac{(n)_{r+s}(a)_r\left(-\dfrac{c}{p}\right)^r\left(-\dfrac{m}{p}\right)^s}{(b)_{r+s}r!s!}=\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}\Gamma(n)}{p^n}\Phi_1\left(n,a,b;-\dfrac{c}{p},-\dfrac{m}{p}\right)$

Comment: @HarryPeter You are right about the mistake; unfortunately  my "fixes" so far haven't yielded anything usable.  My usage of \Phi_2() was from the bottom of page 385 of Bateman Vol1 Integral transforms.  http://authors.library.caltech.edu/43489/  incorrectly extended (:  ..  The other problem I found here and in another of my solutions is the summation on u is finite.  In order to deal with this I suspect that something like (-r-s)_(r+s)/(r+s)_(r+s) is required to terminate the series.  There is an alternative but .. it's an apples/oranges thing: Cb(r_s,u) binomial.  I'll be back.

Comment: For the skill of converting the finite series into the hypergeometric-type functions, you can refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_series.

Comment: I am not quite prefered to call for the Humbert-type series of three variables since the $n$ in here is only a natural number, it should be better to just need to call for the Humbert-type series of two variables. Does this possible for the first term?

Comment: I have been (re)examing Zeilberger/Gosper approaches and they seem quite usable; and have the machine doing the calculations.  A particular item I found interesting is the first equation under "4.5 Multivariate and \q" generalizations" in A=B http://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/aeqb/AeqB.pdf .  It implies that the separation of parameters and variables is porous.  I am using the program Reduce and following http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9412228.pdf ; the combination seems quite easy and cheap (I am retired on a limited budjet).  It accepts all forms of itereation pochhammer, binomial, and gamma. --cont--